# System.out.println messages in JBoss EAP 6.2 logs

Tags: logging, jboss

I am deploying to JBoss EAP 6.
My application is issuing some `System.out.println` calls that I would like to see on the JBoss console.

Currently I don't see any messages there. My WAR has a `logging.properties` file with the following contents:

```
org.apache.catalina.session.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

I need those settings to debug some situations (e.g. like [this one](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/03/18/debugging-the-dreaded-severe-error-listenerstart-and-severe-error-filterstart-tomcat-error-messages/)) as the output on the JBoss console is too terse otherwise.

However, when the `logging.properties` file is present I don't see my `System.out.println` messages in JBoss console. When I remove the `logging.properties` file from the WAR I see them normally.

Why is that? What is wrong with my `logging.properties` file that prevents my `System.out.println` messages to show up in JBoss console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up posting this to developer.jboss.org in [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/message/967201?et=watches.email.thread). TL;DR is that configuring logging be means of a configuration file bundled with your WAR deployment is horribly broken and undocument in JBoss 6.x. Apparently the only supported method (that's reasonably well documented) is to configure logging on the server side. The latter does seem to work fine.