# logging System.out.println getting lost in JBoss

Tags: java, logging, jboss, jboss6.x

I am using simple `System.out.printf` / `System.out.println` statements to perform JBoss logging (I am deploying to JBoss EAP 6.2). I have noticed that when an exception occurs I tend to lose `println` messages immediately preceding the throwing of the exception. This makes it impossible to debug the exception.

To verify this, I put in my WAR the following code:

```
 System.out.println("foo");
 int i = 0; if (i==0) throw new RuntimeException();
 ...
```

(the `int i = 0; if (i==0)` part is just to silence the compiler which would otherwise complain)

Indeed, when this code is executed, in the server's log file (`standalone/log/server.log`) I don't see `foo` at all. I see the reporting of the exception but nothing above it.

I tried printing the same message 100 times in a loop, explicitly doing a `System.out.flush()` and doing a `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1)` before throwing the exception. Nothing changed, no output at all is seen in `server.log`. Only the exception trace shows, but no `foo` above it.

I understand that JBoss wraps the `std:out` and `std:err` into its own logging framework and I am hypothesizing that there is some kind of buffering involved that causes `System.out.println` output to be lost.

I don't have any `logging.properties` file in my WAR and have not modified the standard configuration I am using (`standalone-full.xml`) with respect to logging. I used to have a `logging.properties` file but I removed it as it caused **all** `System.out.println` to be lost as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41371097/274677). Once the `logging.properties` file is removed, *some* `System.out.println` output is at least seen except right before an exception, i.e. when I need it the most.

My questions are:

1. why am I losing this output and how can I ensure that `System.out.println` is always included in `server.log` ?
2. what are some tips to simplify the logging situation in JBoss? The whole thing very complex and undocumented.

Comment: I have multiple applications deployed in JBoss. In some apps, even I'm not using any specific logger framework and working with System.out only. I've never faced any such issue. Can you try (Remote) debugging your code in some IDE such as Eclipse?

Comment: I would suggest using a logging framework SLF4J with logback or log4j

Comment: @RAS tagged this as JBoss 6.x (it's 6.2 actually).

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus, Yes I'm also using JBoss 6.x. Please try debugging your code in Eclipse, which is not printing the output.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was another `logging.properties` file lurking around. Once I removed it I could again seen all `System.out.println` messages on the `server.log` trail. It's still not clear to me why the presence of `logging.properties` files should mess-up with plain `STD:OUT` output.

## Update

Tried to follow the suggestion by **James R. Perkins** to try add a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file in my `META-INF` directory to disable processing of my component by the logging subsystem and added the following:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">   
   <deployment>
    <exclusions>
     <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
     <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
    </exclusions>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

… this didn't work. `System.out.println` output was still lost. So the only workaround is to remove the `logging.properties` and `log4j.xml` files. Thanks to **James R. Perkins** for suggesting this may in fact be a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1070453) in JBoss EAP 6.2.0

Comment: It allows users to include their own logging configuration within their deployment. If you don't want to remove the logging.properties file you could just add a `jboss-deployment-descriptor.xml` and exclude the logging subsystem from processing your deployment.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins If I were to "exclude the logging subsystem from processing my deployment" would I still see plain old System.out.println messages on `server.log` ?

Comment: Yes. They are wrapped in loggers and your deployment would use the server level logging context.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Added a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` (not `-descriptor` maybe that's a typo in your comment?) but nothing happens (see update at the end of the question). The `System.out.println` output is still lost. So the only workaround is to remove `log4j.xml` and `logging.properties` files.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it should be `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. I meant exclude the `logging` subsystem. `<exclude-subsystems><subsystem name="logging"/></exclude-subsystems>` https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile

Answer (score -1):

Ran into same issue as that of the op and found [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/363564). It essentially says you should add

```
<console-handler name="STDOUT">
  <level name="INFO"/>
  <formatter>
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%s%E%n"/>
  </formatter>
</console-handler>
<logger category="stdout" use-parent-handlers="false">
  <level name="INFO"/>
  <handlers>
    <handler name="STDOUT"/>
  </handlers>
</logger>
```

to your JBoss logging subsystem in standalone.xml or domain.xml or using CLI, you can do:

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=STDOUT:add(level=INFO,formatter="%s%E%n")
/subsystem=logging/logger=stdout:add(level=INFO,handlers=[handler=STDOUT],use-parent-handlers=false)
```

You can do the same for STDERR by replacing "stdout" with "stderr".

The above configuration works thus:

- Adds a second ConsoleHandler
- This will be used just for calls to System.out.println(...).
- Defines the stdout logger
- This is used by JBoss Logging anyways, but here we explicitly define it so we can configure it.
- Add the STDOUT handler only to the stdout logger
- Set use-parent-handler=false so we don't get duplicate logging
- Change the formatter pattern in the second ConsoleHandler so it will simply print  the string as-is — no extra formatting.

This implies that you may not need to remove your logging.properties and log4j.xml files. Hopefully, this solves the problem.