# System.out.println stop writing to WildFly server.log after run CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr()

Tags: java, crystal-reports, log4j, wildfly

The java code like this:

```
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.ISessionMgr;
...
        System.out.println("1. before getSessionMgr");
        ISessionMgr sm = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
        System.out.println("2. after getSessionMgr");
```

The code running well on JBoss7, JDK 1.6. That is server.log showed `1. before getSessionMgr` then `2. after getSessionMgr`.

Then it is compiled with JDK 1.8 and deploy to WildFly23, the server.log only showed `1. before getSessionMgr` but no `2. after getSessionMgr`. I know the code has been run to the end because the method output is got as expected. Only the log is missing from server.log. Afterward,  System.out.println can no longer write to server.log. When the same method runs again, even the first log  `1. before getSessionMgr` cannot be written.

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905471/logging-system-out-println-getting-lost-in-jboss), I deleted all log4j.properties and log4j.xml in the deployment, as well as from jar inside lib, but does not help.

About the crystal report library, CrystalEnterprise is in cesession.jar
Implementation-Title: Crystal Enterprise SDK session
Implementation-Version: 14.2.5.2618

Any idea why this happened and how to solve this?

I have think of if crystal report library has run [System.setOut](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) and permenantly redirected the output steam to elsewhere. How can I prevent this?

Comment: There is nothing in WildFly you can do to prevent this if Crystal Reports is overriding stdout.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not sure if crystal report overriding stdout. But it is not happening when running on JBoss. So it looks that may be way to prevent.

Comment: By default WildFly redirects `stdout` and `stderr` to a logger. I have to assume if `System.out.println()` does not end up in the `server.log` then something outside of WildFly is setting the `stdout` to something different.

Comment: Yes, i also think in this way. [System.setOut(PrintStream out)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-) can redirect the stdout, subject to SecurityManager checking. What I guess maybe in JBoss, there is SecurityManager setup by default and disallowed the redirect. And there is no such default on WildFly. Any idea how to setup on WildFly?

Comment: No. WildFly and JBoss EAP do not setup the security manager by default. You'd have to enable it explicitly. The only way I can think of to see what is going on is debug the startup and deploy with a breakpoint on `System.setOut()`.